# Convert Android project to 'regular' Java project inside Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, build, project

Ive inherited some code which started out as an Android project but really is just an API to be used by other applications. Hence, the 'build' process usually just produces a JAR file. The problem Im having is that I get errors from the Android build tools in my console which seem to fire everytime I make a change to some files. How do I fix that?

Im using Eclipse 3.5 (Galileo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Check **run configuration** and remove any reference to the Android Sdk.
- Create a new Java project and copy project files from the older Android project to the new Java one.

Comment: The .project file is the one to replace.  Also the .classpath file may need to be modified if it contains Android references.

Answer (score 1):

You should copy files: .classpath and .project from other working java project. Next you should edit .project with text editor and change SampleProject to YourProjectName