# Convert Android project to Java Project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm in a real bind. I need to convert this Android project into a java project and I cant just make a new one and drag the files over because this one is already hooked up to version control. I did the things mentioned in this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569315/convert-android-project-to-regular-java-project-inside-eclipse) but I still have an error that says

"AndroidManifest.xml is missing"

The problem is that is what I want! How do I tell eclipse that this is not an error.

Jake

Answer (score 0):

Well, guess I figured it out. Had to move the .project and .classpath files over first before deleting the AndroidManifest.xml. That was easy >_>