# How do I run Andengine project as a Java Application if its source code is for Android?

Tags: java, android, andengine

I'm trying to get the sketchytruck example to work in Java. Its found [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=sketchytruck%20andengine&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CD8QFjAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fsebnil%2FSketchy-Truck%2Ftree%2Fmaster%2Fandengine&ei=lwU5UdDrGYzU0gHm9YGwBA&usg=AFQjCNFtmtAxpZG8TVq_gB0ia_XwGzdgWg&bvm=bv.43287494,d.dmQ). Before anyone gives me the "you didn't look hard enough", I have. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569315/convert-android-project-to-regular-java-project-inside-eclipse) and I followed the directions doing everything but now I'm getting an error that says Selection does not contain a main type. I created a main type

```
package se.treplex.sketchytruck;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import se.treplex.sketchytruck.GameActivity;

public class SketchyDesktop {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new LwjglApplication(new GameActivity(), "SketchyTruck", 320, 480, false);
    }
}
```

Then it says LwjglApplication cannot be resolved to a type. So I tried fix project setup which didn't do anything. I notice GameActivity extends LayoutGameActivity and I spent about 3 hours googling for andengine source that runs as a java application with no luck. So my question is what main do I use to get this working as a Java Application? If there isn't one then how do you get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

AndEngine has a few (minor) Android dependencies. (Logging, Activity subclasses, GLSurfaceView subclass, ...). Without changes it will ONLY run on Android (And BlackBerry 10).

Comment: So it's not possible to run with Java. That's exactly what I needed to know. Good answer.